# How to break a columnar transposition cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, classical-cipher, transposition-cipher

I'm currently studying for a cryptography exam. I've been given ciphertext that has been encrypted by a columnar transposition cipher. I've been given no shift key length or key word, the only thing I know is that only 2 columns have been shifted.

How can I determine the key? Or better yet, is there another way to decipher the ciphertext?

Comment: I am not looking for someone to decipher, simply to assist in how I would go about this. I find myself going around in circles.

Comment: Are you allowed to just perform plain brute-force? BTW: The #1 technique for this would be *sliding window*.

Comment: *" the only thing I know is that only 2 columns have been shifted."* - So you don't have just a [simple columnar transposition cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columnar_transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition) but rather some combination of a columnar transposition and a shift cipher?

Answer (score 1):

(Although your question is for a long time ago) Transposition ciphers don't change the frequency of letters in their ciphertexts. So, you can implement a [frequency attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis). For decryption by this you only need the table of frequency of English letters and your ciphertext.
(Your encryption scheme here is a [Columnar transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition) with a key that all its letters are in order except 2 of them.)